# What's the difference between these two versions of highlighting in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

What's the difference between the solid and segmented highlighting here? Visual studio changes between them occasionally, but I've never noticed the moment it happens so I can't figure out what the difference is.

[image: green bars]

(The green itself indicates that the changes on that line have been saved.)

Comment: Do you have any steps which reproduce the second example?  Intuition says this is just a bug but I'm unable to repro it so I can't tell for sure

Comment: @JaredPar: I'm afraid not. I currently have a VS 2010 open with a C# project that's in this state, but I've no idea how it got there. Could easily be a bug - funny that I didn't really consider that!

Comment: Are you using tabs ro spaces in this project?

Comment: Spaces. (Had to check!)